# Retrieve Values As Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following table in my PHPMYADMIN

[image]

The desired output is

> **headline**                              **impressions**              **clicks**
>
> Buy A new
>   Iphone                 
>   1                                  1
>
> Buy New Android Phone        1
>                                   1

I tried the following SQL query but it did not work:

```
SELECT headline, count(distinct(tracking_type)) FROM `tracking`
```

How to do it with the `CASE` statments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If types are fixed (just IMPRESSION and CLICK), you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  headline,
  SUM(tracking_type='IMPRESSION') AS impressions,
  SUM(tracking_type='CLICK') AS clicks
FROM
  tracking
GROUP BY
  headline
```

Comment: Yes obviously they are fixed. Your query is working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> How to do it with the CASE statements.

The same as in @fthiella's answer, but with `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT headline,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tracking_type='IMPRESSION' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS impressions,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tracking_type='CLICK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS clicks
FROM tracking
GROUP BY headline
```